# Splunk: Throttling of alerts

Tags: alert, splunk

I have configured an alert which runs every ten minutes and is triggered if the number of events is bigger than zero. I want this alert to be triggered or rather the mail for this alert to be sent only when it appears the first time. And the next email should then be sent if the alert condition is triggered for example one hour after the first mail. So, what I did I checked the throttle box and chose as time frame there to suppress the next trigger for one hour.

What I want to achieve here is this for example:
Alert condition was triggered at 8:00 a.m. Additionally at 8:30 a.m., 8:55 a.m and at 9:05 a.m. Then I would like to receive in total two alerts. One at 8:00 a.m. and the other one at 9:10.

Do I get exactly this by the configurations I described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is what your throttling configuration will do.